# Fetch response gives JSON but needs to be `await` again, when used in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write a common api service.
get.js is has 'get' api code. In get.js, I see `response` which is in `json` format. But when I call it in `app.js`, it's not received in `json`, I have to again `await` in order to use it? why?

// get.js

```js
const getData = async (url) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    console.log("responseJson: ", responseJson); // response is coming in json format
    return responseJson; // returning that same `json`
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
  }
  return [];
};
export default getData;
```

`responseJson` is in json format, which is being `returned`.

// App.js

```js
import "./styles.css";
import getData from "./get";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [demoData, setDemoData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const json = await getData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"); // why again I need to 'await'? rather than directly using the json.
      // console.log("json: ", json);
      setDemoData(json);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {demoData.map((data) => {
        console.log("data: ", data);
        return <p>{data.name}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have to do `await getData()`, why is it like that?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-api-call-sofl-6mth3t) demo.

Comment: `async` functions return a Promise - to access the result of a promise, you use `await` ... or `promise.then` of course - contrary to what your code expects, an `async` function does not return an asynchronous result synchronously, because with current computer technology, it is simply not possible for the code to predict the future

Comment: promises are a nicer way to use callbacks that alleviate "callback hell" or the "callback pyramid of doom" ... though, they dont' completely eradicate the issue in all cases ... that's where async/await comes in, syntax sugar for promises (not just any old asynchrony - only promises) that further "flatten" the code - neither of these change the nature of asynchrony - asynchrony is always asynchronous - so, once you introduce asynchrony into your code, it affects everything it touches, so you must learn to embrace it and code for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `getData` function is an `async` one and you have to await in the app.js file because there are actions in `getData` that can take time and you don't get back result instantly.

So, in app.js file you have to `await` until all the process is finished inside `getData` and json response is sent back from there.

If you don't use await in `app.js` then, the code after the line ( where you are calling the getData method ) will be executed before you have received the response from the API.